# Pausing Carousel while swiping over items

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, touch, swipe

I am using a bootstrap 3 carousel with some images.

It is automatically sliding, and for mobile devices swipe I used a script from here : **https://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Smooth-Touch-enabled-Carousel-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html**.

---

I want to pause the auto-sliding while I am not decided which photo to see, in a situation like this :
[image]

---

Otherwise, if the carousel is not paused from sliding, if I stay too much with the touchswipe like in the photo the carousel will change the picture even though I am targeting to view another one.

I think in a human language would be like that :

- **pause the carousel while swiping through images**
- **restart the auto-sliding after swiping or after letting go of the carousel touch**

## There is the carousel code :

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8700">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=114">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=62">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=315">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=622">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=401">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->

  </div>

</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="carousel-swipe.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( ".carousel" ).carousel({ interval: false });
   </script>
```

## And there is the script for swipe :

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  if ( !$.fn.carousel ) {
    throw new Error( "carousel-swipe required bootstrap carousel" )
  }

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var CarouselSwipe = function(element) {
    this.$element    = $(element)
    this.carousel    = this.$element.data('bs.carousel')
    this.options     = $.extend({}, CarouselSwipe.DEFAULTS, this.carousel.options)
    this.startX      =
    this.startY      =
    this.startTime   =
    this.cycling     =
    this.$active     =
    this.$items      =
    this.$next       =
    this.$prev       =
    this.dx          = null
    this.sliding     = false

    this.$element
      .on('touchstart',        $.proxy(this.touchstart,this))
      .on('touchmove',         $.proxy(this.touchmove,this))
      .on('touchend',          $.proxy(this.touchend,this))
      .on('slide.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.startSliding, this))
      .on('slid.bs.carousel',  $.proxy(this.stopSliding, this))
  }

  CarouselSwipe.DEFAULTS = {
    swipe: 30 // percent per second
  }

  CarouselSwipe.prototype.startSliding = function() {
    this.sliding = true
  }

  CarouselSwipe.prototype.stopSliding = function() {
    this.sliding = false
  }

  CarouselSwipe.prototype.touchstart = function(e) {
    if (this.sliding || !this.options.swipe) return;
    var touch = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0] : e
    this.dx = 0
    this.startX = touch.pageX
    this.startY = touch.pageY
    this.cycling = null
    this.width = this.$element.width()
    this.startTime = e.timeStamp

  }

  CarouselSwipe.prototype.touchmove = function(e) {
    if (this.sliding || !this.options.swipe || !this.startTime) return;
    var touch = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0] : e
    var dx = touch.pageX - this.startX
    var dy = touch.pageY - this.startY
    if (Math.abs(dx) < Math.abs(dy)) return; // vertical scroll

    if ( this.cycling === null ) {
      this.cycling = !!this.carousel.interval
      this.cycling && this.carousel.pause()
    }

    e.preventDefault()
    this.dx = dx / (this.width || 1) * 100
    this.swipe(this.dx)
  }

  CarouselSwipe.prototype.touchend = function(e) {
    if (this.sliding || !this.options.swipe || !this.startTime) return;
    if (!this.$active) return; // nothing moved
    var all = $()
      .add(this.$active).add(this.$prev).add(this.$next)
      .carousel_transition(true)

    var dt = (e.timeStamp - this.startTime) / 1000
    var speed = Math.abs(this.dx / dt) // percent-per-second
    if (this.dx > 40 || (this.dx > 0 && speed > this.options.swipe)) {
      this.carousel.prev()
    } else if (this.dx < -40 || (this.dx < 0 && speed > this.options.swipe)) {
      this.carousel.next();
    } else {
      this.$active
        .one($.support.transition.end, function () {
          all.removeClass('prev next')
        })
      .emulateTransitionEnd(this.$active.css('transition-duration').slice(0, -1) * 1000)
    }

    all.css('transform', '')
    this.cycling && this.carousel.cycle()
    this.$active = null // reset the active element
    this.startTime = null
  }

  CarouselSwipe.prototype.swipe = function(percent) {
    var $active = this.$active || this.getActive()
    if (percent < 0) {
        this.$prev
            .css('transform', 'translate3d(0,0,0)')
            .removeClass('prev')
            .carousel_transition(true)
        if (!this.$next.length || this.$next.hasClass('active')) return
        this.$next
            .carousel_transition(false)
            .addClass('next')
            .css('transform', 'translate3d(' + (percent + 100) + '%,0,0)')
    } else {
        this.$next
            .css('transform', '')
            .removeClass('next')
            .carousel_transition(true)
        if (!this.$prev.length || this.$prev.hasClass('active')) return
        this.$prev
            .carousel_transition(false)
            .addClass('prev')
            .css('transform', 'translate3d(' + (percent - 100) + '%,0,0)')
    }

    $active
        .carousel_transition(false)
        .css('transform', 'translate3d(' + percent + '%, 0, 0)')
  }

  CarouselSwipe.prototype.getActive = function() {
    this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    this.$items = this.$active.parent().children()

    this.$next = this.$active.next()
    if (!this.$next.length && this.options.wrap) {
      this.$next = this.$items.first();
    }

    this.$prev = this.$active.prev()
    if (!this.$prev.length && this.options.wrap) {
      this.$prev = this.$items.last();
    }

    return this.$active;
  }

  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  var old = $.fn.carousel
  $.fn.carousel = function() {
    old.apply(this, arguments);
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel.swipe')
      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel.swipe', new CarouselSwipe(this))
    })
  }

  $.extend($.fn.carousel,old);

  $.fn.carousel_transition = function(enable) {
    enable = enable ? '' : 'none';
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this)
        .css('-webkit-transition', enable)
        .css('transition', enable)
    })
  };

}(jQuery);
```

#### I know there is too much code, but any idea of how to solve would be very helpful!

Comment: u want to pause on touch in mobile and web, pause  on mouse over ?

Comment: Sorry, I know I haven't made myself clear from the start. No, I want to pause the carousel just on mobile, when I am not decided what picture to see, like in the photo above.
In other words, I want to point out that the carousel is designed like here : **https://codepen.io/andrearufo/pen/rVWpyE** , but this javascript didn't work for me.

Comment: Also, when I'm saying "not decided" I refer to the situation, you probably know, when you are between the two consecutive items (on mobile) of a carousel, and in that time the auto-sliding goes on, fact which produces the change of the image before I swipe left or right. I hope you understood.

Comment: I want to add that the javascript codepen code doen't behave like my plugin from the external link mentioned above. Thx for reading this amount of explanations :))